# Restore precomputed index

Tags: dask

I have approx. 1.5 TB of data stored in `csv` files.
I have loaded it with dask and computed index with `.set_index(sorted=True)`. The operation took 9 hours. Now my dataframe has got divisions filled with some sensible values.

Is is possible to store the computed index in separate file so that I can reliably restore it next time I read these same csv files? I am using `dask 0.18.2`.

So far I have tried storing value of `.divisions` and `.npartitions` to pickle file and passing them to the `.set_index` method afterwards. The funny thing this seems to work on my PC only in a python virtual environment, where the index was computed.
But as soon as I switch to different python virtual environment on the same PC, which has exactly same dask version, the amount of partitions after read_csv(`*.csv`) differs significantly and I can not use the precomputed divisions directly. If I set the partitions and divisions for that dataframe from the stored values, I get inconsistent (different) results on getting the data by index.

So what is the right way of restoring `csv` a precomputed csv index, without converting to the different storage format like parquet?

Comment: Are these different python environments different versions of python? Have you verified that the unpickled version of your index is exactly the same as when you saved it? Maybe the data is a different data type (32-bit integer versus 64-bit) than you are expecting or a different pickle protocol is being used for some reason. Just some ideas.

Comment: Also worth checking the character encoding/language settings in each environment.

Comment: But in short, JSON is a more robust and portable storage format than pickle, for types it can handle.

Comment: Helllo guys: here are the packages of the first environment which works with stored index:
https://pastebin.com/TRRcx1xZ

And here are the packages of the environment which does not work with the index:
https://pastebin.com/MHuKksHS

Comment: @djhoese these are all python3 (python 3.6.5) environments

Comment: @mdurant thx for the answer, but I do not have problems with storage of index. The problems is more about reusability of the index.

Comment: language settings in each of the environments are exactly the same.
locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_NAME=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_ALL=

Answer (score 0):

here is the resolution:

The first python environment has pstuils, the second python environment does not have.

If psutils module is missing, read_csv is automatically setting blocksize parameter to a constant number (something like 256**2), if psutils python module is installed, then blocksize is automatically computed based on amount of virtual memory and number of cpus (mem // cpus / 10). The number of partitions of the data is directly derived from the block size.

So to be able to restore the index, one has to store the *blocksize* it has been computed with and pass the *blocksize* parameter to read_csv function.

Unfortunatly dask does not really document this behavour, but just says, that the *number of partitions* is automatically computed somehow. But they did not say, that it depends on the psutils module.

This is great, that dask is an open source product, because that way it was very easy possible to find out, what is happening.